# json as DB for Django

Tags: python, json, django, database

I am new to Django and I just want to know if it is possible to give Django a json file instead of creating a DB or models.

Basically, I have json with info that should appear in front end and it can be updated frequently. Is it possible to check in somewhere that json - as a DB for django. and in `views.py` to parse that json and create elements?

Will that work? Or I should create models for each element from json? And update/migrate each time models/db?

I hope I have managed to ask a right question.

Comment: Yes you can absolutely do this, just open and read the file each time the function in `views.py` is called. It's a terrible idea though if the file is frequently being updated since you'll get simultaneous reads and writes at some point. Why don't you want to use a database of some sort?

Comment: You can use postgresql and its [`json data type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html), which is supported natively in django via [`JSONfield`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).

Answer (score 0):

you can try MongoDB, which support bson (very similar like json).
The guide for MongoDB can be found at :
https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `django-nonrel` (which is what this engine relies on) is only compatible with django 1.8 and has not been updated in 2 years. This is not a recommended solution.